# How to add meta-data Tag to AndroidManifest in ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I want to prevent firebase to auto init the Instance ID.

Firebase said that I have to add this lines of code to my AndroidManifest:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="firebase_messaging_auto_init_enabled"
    android:value="false" />
<meta-data
    android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_enabled"
    android:value="false" />
```

But i cannot do this in my Ionic 3 Project. I added it to my config.xml file in the  Tag, but it doesnt work. How can I change the Manifest file?

Comment: can u show ur full file of confg

Answer (score 0):

It just works now. I can add the lines to my AndroidManifest.

The lines in the config.xml are:

```
<config-file parent="./application" target="AndroidManifest.xml">
            <meta-data android:name="firebase_messaging_auto_init_enabled" android:value="false" />
            <meta-data android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_enabled" android:value="false" />
        </config-file>
```

And add this to your widget tag inside your config.xml

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

But nothing happens. I can send push notifications without enabling it like Firebase said. So I cannot prevent the auto init stuff.